# Is SwiftUI based on UIKit?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I just finished few SwiftUI tutorials. I like it.
But i don't understand how it render list of declarations.
Is it translated to UIKit at the end? Or it use something new?

Comment: Some parts might be translated to UIKit/Cocoa, at least for now. It shouldn't really matter for us.